# How can I print to HP 3800 printer via wi-fi?

Tags: printing, laser-printer, wireless-networking

My initial idea was to stick a Wi-Fi dongle into HP 3800 usb port, but is it going to work? This is not the network version (HP 3800n). Is it possible to turn it somehow into a wifi printer?  I need to print from Linux and Android

Answer (score 2):

You can't simply plug in a normal USB dongle. The printer's software won't recognise what is going on.

What you're going to need is a "Wireless USB Printer Adapter". HP will sell you their own product for this; just make sure that when you purchase one, it doesn't have compatibility issues with any of your network hardware.

You'll find hundreds of products by just typing "Wireless USB Printer Adapter" in google. Take a pick!

Comment: Great! That's what I expected. From quick search it turned out, unsurprisingly, that wireless USB printer adapters come usually with software for Windows. I need to print from Linux and Android. Or maybe it might be possible to print via Linksys router? Anybody had any experience with similar configuration?

Comment: It really depends on how much usage you give the printer. If it's "mission critical", you might consider simply buying a Print Server that plugs into your network and will work with all of your OSs.